# Why is it not allowed to assign double literal to variable of type float?

Tags: java, numeric, integer-promotion, type-promotion

In java, the compiler throws an error if you try to assign a double literal to an int variable. However, it allows the assignment of an int literal to variable of type long.

```
    double d = 4.0;
    float f = d; // this is not allowed. 4.0 should be 4.0f

    int i = 4;
    long x = i; // this is allowed. 4 is treated same as 4L
```

Comment: You've basically got `int` and `long` the wrong way round, meaning you're not doing a fair comparison. If you had `long i = 4; int x = i;` then you'd have the same issue.

Comment: your int/long example would be equivalent to `double d = f;`. `long x = 4L; int i = x;` will not work either

Answer (score 4):

Because an `int` fits inside a `long`, but if you put a `double` inside a `float` you may lose precision (it's a narrower type).

If you really must you can force this via casting

```
double d = 4.0;
float f = (float)d; // this is allowed
```

Answer (score 2):

Because they are of different types and widths.  Since you are losing precision going from a double to a float or an long to a int you need to downcast.

```
double d = 4.0;
float f = (float)d;

long i = 4;
int x = (int)i;
```

For the integer types, you can detect [overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow) by calling  [`Math.toIntExact`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Math.html#toIntExact(long)), and trapping for [`ArithmeticException`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ArithmeticException.html).

```
try{
    int myInt = Math.toIntExact( myLong ) 
} catch (ArithmeticException e) {
    …
}
```